# C# move a window to secondary screen

Tags: c#, google-chrome, browser

Hello fellow developers

I have a little question. I have a problem that's starting to annoy me.

I have written a program in C# which opens the Chrome Browser.
However, the Chrome Browser always opens at the place where it was last opened.
Is there a possibility to put the browser window directly on the second screen at every start?
My goal is that the Chrome Browser always starts automatically on the other screen.

Anybody got an idea?

Thank you

Comment: Could you maybe post some example code as to how you opening the browser?

Answer (score 7):

You could try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

...........................

```
public void StartChrome()
{
    var allScreens = Screen.AllScreens.ToList();

    var screenOfChoice = allScreens[1]; // repllace with your own logic

    var chromeProcess = new Process
    {
            StartInfo =
            {
                    Arguments = "https://www.google.com --new-window --start-fullscreen",
                    FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            }
    };

    chromeProcess.Start();

    // Needed to move the the process.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    // setting the x value here can help you determmine which screen to move the process to
    // 0 will be the first screen, and the '.WorkingArea.Right' value to the previous screen's '.WorkingArea.Right' would change which 
    // screen to display it on.
    MoveWindow(chromeProcess.MainWindowHandle, screenOfChoice.WorkingArea.Right, screenOfChoice.WorkingArea.Top, screenOfChoice.WorkingArea.Width, screenOfChoice.WorkingArea.Height, false);
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int X, int Y, int nWidth, int nHeight, bool bRepaint);
```

EDIT:

Just to explain further, if you have 3 screens with a resolution of `1920x1080` setting the `x` parameter in the `MoveWindow()` method will place the window at the left most place of the first screen, setting the `x` parameter to `1920` will place the application on the second screen, setting the `x` parameter to `3840` the process would be on the third screen. With having access to all the screens and their widths, you should be able to accurately place the process on the screen of choice almost all the time unless a user has custom ordering of their multi screen layout, then I'm not 100% sure if this would be ideal.

EDIT 2:

The above code will not work on `.NetCore 2.2` and lower as it uses `System.Windows.Forms` which I believe will only be introduced in `.NetCore 3.0`